# Redirect on catching an exception in a method in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, models

I am using Authlogic-connect to connect various service providers. There is a method in user.rb

```
def complete_oauth_transaction
      token = token_class.new(oauth_token_and_secret)
      old_token = token_class.find_by_key_or_token(token.key, token.token)
      token = old_token if old_token

      if has_token?(oauth_provider)
        self.errors.add(:tokens, "you have already created an account using your #{token_class.service_name} account, so it")
      else
        self.access_tokens << token
      end
    end
```

When a service provider is already added it gives the error as stated in the  has_token? method and the page breaks. I need to redirect the app to the same page and flash the error. How do i do this? I have overridden the method in my own user.rb so that I can change the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, well you could put a method that handles the error that has_token? throws, and tell your controller to redirect that exact error.  something like this in your controller:

`rescue_from OauthError::RecordNotFound, :with => :deny_access`
then you can put

```
def deny_access
  redirect_to your_view_path, :alert => "Too bad sucker" #some flash message
end
```

Or you could do something like this in the controller:

```
if complete_oauth_transaction.errors.present?
  redirect_to your_view_path
else
  # continue on with the normal code here
end
```

This is how you could generically handle errors.  Your exact code will vary, as this is all we have to go off of.