# How to redirect_to path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this class Method with a rails Exception error private method. I wish that when the condition is met, I should be redirected to the root_path with a notice but instead, am displayed the error message page

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord

  NUMBER_OF_PERMITTED_PHOTOS = 3
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy,before_add: :validate_photo_limit

  private

  def validate_photo_limit(photo)
    raise Exception.new if photos.size >= NUMBER_OF_PERMITTED_PHOTOS
  end

end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect on catching an exception in a method in the model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535507/redirect-on-catching-an-exception-in-a-method-in-the-model)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But I don't understand. how the code should look like

Comment: Basically, if you put http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from in your controller, you can run a method when an error happens. So put versions of the top two code chunks into your application controller (or wherever). You will probably want to raise a more specific error, in your model, though. Don't worry about the "Or you could do something like this..." part.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most elegant way of achieving this is by creating a specific class for your error and then adding a rescue_from statement in your ApplicationController.

So let's say this is your model.

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  class NumberOfPhotosError < StandardError; end
  NUMBER_OF_PERMITTED_PHOTOS = 3
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy,before_add: :validate_photo_limit

  private

  def validate_photo_limit(photo)
    raise NumberOfPhotosError.new if photos.size >= NUMBER_OF_PERMITTED_PHOTOS
  end
end
```

Then, assuming you have a controller that inherits from ApplicationController, it should look something like this. Of course, you can also use the rescue_from statement in specific controllers, if you don't wish to add it to your parent controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from Listing::NumberOfPhotosError do |error|
    redirect_to(root_path, notice: 'Incorrect number of photos!')
  end
end
```